# ¿Cuál es el verbo que implica que algo te gusta en mayor grado?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, significado

En la película *Ratatouille* hay un diálogo bastante divertido en el que Linguini le recrimina a Ego que está demasiado delgado como para gustarle la comida, a lo que este responde:

> Es que a mí no me gusta la comida, me apasiona.

En español hay muchos verbos que indican que algo te agrada en mayor o menor cantidad:

- *[gustar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JueNX6F)*,
- *[encantar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Ez09pdw%7CEz0jscS)* (gustar en gran medida),
- *[entusiasmar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Fqd1I28)* (que infunde entusiasmo: exaltación y fogosidad del ánimo),
- *[apasionar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=36SMlGY)* (que causa pasión: afición vehemente a algo)...

En un principio "apasionar" parece ser un buen candidato, pero ya por preguntar: ¿existe algún verbo que implique que algo te gusta aún más que algo que te apasiona o entusiasma? ¿Cuál sería el más intenso de todos esos verbos?

Comment: También tenemos otros, como *amar, adorar, fascinar, enloquecer* (los dos primeros obviamente sólo con el OD, sin el OI).

Comment: Añadamos _chiflar_ a la lista.

Comment: Añade también el coloquial "flipar".

Comment: Creo que en general _encantar_ es la elección correcta. Aquí el _apasiona_ agrega un matiz distinto: no sólo gusta mucho al apetito (encanta), sino que impulsa toda una forma de vida (apasiona).

Comment: Yo usaría me encanta como superior a me gusta y lo uso de manera coloquial y en la vida diaria. Me apasiona me suena poco común y es una palabra muy alardeante en mi opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No estoy seguro de si existe un "superlativo" de gustar.

Personalmente estoy de acuerdo en que `encantar`, `entusiasmar` y `apasionar` son en cierto sentido sinónimos y ninguno destaca realmente por encima de los otros.

Para mí el siguiente nivel sería "[obsesionar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QpAN3cZ)". Aquello que causa [obsesión](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Qp4ig6r) "condiciona una determinada actitud". El problema es que no creo que "obsesionar" tenga por defecto las cualidades positivas de "gustar" o "apasionar" y necesitarías obtener un poco de contexto. Aparte, puede ser **subjetivo** si una "afición [vehemente](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bRK5I3F)" (Que obra de forma irreflexiva, dejándose llevar por los impulsos) es más poderosa que una que "condiciona la actitud".

Quizá "**amar**" sí sea un verbo con las connotaciones positivas de "gustar" que expresa un grado superior (aunque no voy a proclamar que sea *superlativo*) de afecto, atracción o agrado por o hacia algo.

Sigo pensando que "obsesión" es más fuerte, pero contiene distintos matices que "amar".

> Es que a mí no me gusta la comida, me **obsesiona**.
>
> Es que a mí no me gusta la comida. Yo **amo** la comida.

---

Como nota, he encontrado [esta entrada a la hispanoteca](http://hispanoteca.eu/Foro-preguntas/ARCHIVO-Foro/Encantar%20-%20gustar%20mucho.htm), en la que se pregunta por qué "encantar" a diferencia de "gustar" no admite ciertos adverbios (decimos "Esto me gusta **mucho**" pero no "Esto me encanta *mucho*". Es simplemente "Esto me encanta").

> Encantar es un verbo superlativo de por sí y no admite gradación. Es un verbo que tiene un sema de mayor intensidad, expresa máxima intensificación. [...] Por su grado de máxima intensidad, encantar no admite comparación.

Comment: De hecho creo que, independientemente de lo subjetivo (solo la intuición de cada hablante nativo podrá establecer una gradación de intensidad en muchos de estos verbos), el criterio más objetivo es ese: si no admite "mucho", es que ya se encuentra *al 100 %*, mientras que si admite adverbios de ese tipo es que todavía no ha llegado a ese 100 %.

Al menos así les explico yo a mis alumnos de ELE que "encantar" no admite "mucho", que "favorito" y "preferido" no admiten "más", etc. :)

Answer (score 0):

El español tiene una fuerte raíz cristiana católica, por lo que tu pregunta se responde por palabras con alusiones eclesiásticas del medioevo, llevadas del latín al castellano moderno. Por eso, creo, el verbo amar, estaría por sobre todo los ejemplos que pones. Pero con reservas a la intención buena y adecuada, por otro lado, en lo coloquial, para algo lascivo o dañino, obsesionar se ajusta bien. 
Pero encontrarás más adjetivos que verbos, para un efecto ambivalente entre amar y obsesionar.

Por ejemplo:

> magnífico, ca Del lat. magnifĭcus.
>   1. adj. Espléndido, suntuoso.
>   2. adj. Excelente, admirable.
>   3. adj. U. como título de honor para algunas personas ilustres y hoy, en España, para los rectores universitarios.

Otra palabra muy poco usada en el español hablado:

> magnanimidad Del lat. magnanimĭtas, -ātis.
>   1. f. Grandeza y elevación de ánimo

Existe un verbo/adjetivo/sustantivo que sí se usa en español, pero no es de lengua castellana, sino del griego, que está por sobre toda referencia a los majestuoso, superior, deseable, amable (amar), bello e iluminado, y demás sinónimos en escala de importancia: Tōd. Este concepto, en la fenomenología, filosofía y teología, hace referencia a "lo bello de lo bello". Tiene una aplicación en la estética, por lo que bien vale para referirse al gusto por algo de forma exacerbada y fuera de este mundo.